# Online streaming video/audio financial/stock programs

Tags: united-states, stocks, investing, news

I don't have cable TV, so can't watch CNBC or other financial channels. So can someone suggest some online financial programs? I am looking for both streaming ones (for real-time news) and some talk programs/daily news (which can be downloaded later, and they are usually more organized/detailed on the topics).

For now, I watch the "[Nightly Business Reports](http://nbr.com/category/nbr-shows/)" on Youtube. Hope the community can share what you usually watch/listen to.

Answer (score 1):

The CNBC site is littered with videos. Whenever I click a link to one of their articles, it seems to be a video instead. Not like having the channel streamed, but most of the top stories.

Comment: Watching those CNBC top story clips are painful, because there will be 30 seconds ads up front. And the clips are usually just 1-2 minutes. That's why I was looking for other sources.